# Why does the problem $A u = \lambda u$ bother us in Spectral Theory? Why are we interested in the inverse of $(A - \lambda I)$, and not simply of $A$?

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

I simply don't see why it should be of our interest to check the eigenvalues of an operator and to find the resolvent of an operator.

An eigenvalue here just shows for which $\lambda$ and for which eigenfunction $u$ the equation $A u = \lambda u$ is true, nothing more. But why is this so particularly interesting for us? I really don't get it.

I mean, it just seems like an arbitrary problem, on which the whole Spectral Theory was "build" on. Like: "Look, $Au = \lambda u$ looks like an interesting problem, let's create a whole theory based on this!". Everyone can simply create such a problem, but why should $Au = \lambda u$ bother us so much to the point that we created the whole field of Spectral Theory?

Also, what I don't get is why are we bothering to calculate $(A - \lambda I)^{-1}$, and not simply $A^{-1}$?

Is it maybe because of some problems in physics that we're bothered with $Au = \lambda u$ and the resolvent of $A$? Because I really don't see a purely mathematical motivation behind that

Comment: Eigenvalues are extremely interesting because spectral decompositions are a) Beautiful and b) make calculations and proofs enormously easier

Comment: Maybe think of matrices: if we know the eigenvalues and eigenspaces we get a better understanding of what the matrix is doing. Maybe we can diagonalize and define squareroots or other functions.

Comment: If I gave you an arbitrary matrix and told you to compute the $n$th power e.g. to the power $1000$ you'd have a very hard time without using spectral theory...

Comment: And in an abstract proof we don't know the specific details of the matrices/operators at hand, but if we can talk about their spectra then I can compute $Av=\lambda v$ without further ado.

Comment: @FShrike Your example is just about matrices. I just don't see where the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a e.g. differential operator should be of any kind of use

Comment: @FShrike And what about the resolvent?

Comment: Maybe take some selfadjoint compact operator $T$ on some Hilbert space, then we know $Tx = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu_i (x,x_i)x_i$ for some orthonormal system $(x_i)$, where $\mu_i$ are the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

The question of invertibility $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is precisely the question of solvability of $Ax=\lambda x$.

The spectrum of an operator is of enormous importance to the understanding of the operator. It is the generalization of eigenvalues from linear algebra to the infinite dimensional setting. It shows how an operator may be decomposed into simpler operators. It generalizes diagonalisability. It is the mathematical foundation of quantum mechanics (ev’s of self adjoins operators are possible outcomes of measurements). And so on.

Answer (score 2):

Jakob Elias already gave some motivation in his answer let me add some more.

First of all $A^{-1}$ is just the special case of the resolvent for $\lambda=0$.

Next, spectral theory is crucial in dynamical systems, where you are interested in how flows behave. For example if you have an ODE like
$$ y'(t) = A(t) y(t) $$
where $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow Mat(n\times n, \mathbb{R})$. In general you will have a hard time solving that equation. However, if you settle for the more modest question, what happens at fixed points, you can use spectral theory to approach this.

You could of course again complain that these are just matrices. Sure, but you run into the same issue for a large class of completely integrable evolution equation (KdV, NLS, CM, KP, KP2, ...). There you use some kind of nonlinear Fourier transform, express everything in the eigenvalues of some time-dependent Schrödinger operator, evolve it there and then transform back. This proceedure allows you to define the flow of such equations even for very rough initial data.

A lot of perturbation theory is also heavily based on spectral theory. The underlying question is if you have a PDE and you make some small change in the equation how much will the solution change.

Added: If you can easily come up with such a problems, you will be soon a star among research mathematicians!

Comment: Excellent answer, could be edited and merged with mine.

Comment: @JoakobElias I think your answer is better suited than mine, you give the key reason without any technicalities and is therefore accessible to a wider audience. I just wanted to add some more examples from the fields I am interested in. Somehow I this question is quite entertaining to me as I have the opposite point of view, the spectrum is the main interest and the rest is not too relevant (of course that is not to be taken literally, but at least morally it feels trueto me).